# How can I generate a user password in R

Tags: r, excel, vba

I want to generate a passwort for user in R. Until now I'm using Excel and the following VB-Script. How canIi transform the functionality in an appropriate R script. Thank you very much.

```
myArr = Array("", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", _
            "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M", _
            "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", _
            "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o",
"p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", _
            "!", "§", "$", "%", "&", "(", ")", "*")

intArr = UBound(myArr)
intA = Application.InputBox("Wieviele Passwörter sollen erstellt     werden?", "PasswortGenerator", 10, , , , , 1)
If Not TypeName(intA) = "Boolean" Then
Randomize
intC = ActiveCell.Column
intZ = ActiveCell.Row
For intZ = intZ To intZ + intA 'Anzahl Passwörter
  For intP = 1 To 8 'Anzahl Stellen des Passwortes
    strP = strP & myArr(Int(intArr * Rnd + 1))
  Next intP
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveCell.EntireColumn, strP) = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(intZ, intC).Value = strP
  End If
  strP = ""
Next intZ
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you very much.

OK, from bellow I'm trying to set up a function that will generate a password for each employee (mitarbeiter). I wnat to add a new variable 'passwort' in the function with the generated password for each employee. So, thanks again for your help.

```
genPsw <- function(num, len=8) {
          # Vorgaben für die Passwortkonventionen festlegen
            myArr  <- c("", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", 
                        "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M", 
                        "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", 
                        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o",
                        "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", 
                        "!", "§", "$", "%", "&", "(", ")", "*")
          # replicate is a wrapper for the common use of sapply for repeated evaluation of an expression 
          # (which will usually involve random number generation).
            replicate(num, paste(sample(myArr, size=len, replace=T), collapse=""))
          # Lanege von dataframe mitarbeiter ermitteln
          dim_mitarbeiter <- nrow(mitarbeiter)
          for(i in 1:dim_mitarbeiter) {
                        # Random Number Generation
                          set.seed(i)
                        # Generate Passwort
                        mitarbeiter$passwort <- genPsw(i)                
          }
```

}

Comment: It would be easier if you just told us what requirements you want to meet. Eg. 8 characters long, at least 2 upper and 2 lower case, etc

Comment: Can you please show your own attempts in R, and explain where you had trouble. You are basically asking people to do all your coding from scratch, which is [not the purpose of SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code translation service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
genPsw <- function(num, len=8) {
  myArr  <- c("", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", 
              "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M", 
              "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", 
              "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o",
              "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", 
              "!", "§", "$", "%", "&", "(", ")", "*")
  replicate(num, paste(sample(myArr, size=len, replace=T), collapse=""))
}

set.seed(1)
genPsw(3)
# [1] "JRf§E§&l" "j5ECnSsa" "p*St%Fk9"
```